# Event handle on focus Touchable elements in Android TV

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building an AndroidTV application with React-Native.

I've been referring to the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv) (in Android tab).

I'm trying to use the `touchableHandleActivePressIn` method on element: `TouchableHighlight` / `TouchableOpacity`

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  myMethod = () => {
      console.log('Working');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity touchableHandleActivePressIn={this.myMethod}>
           <Text>Placeholder</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. While I get focus on this element from another element (I'm sure they get focus while I see by changing styles).

In this example, I don't add any placeholder buttons to change focus, but the element isn't working.

I can't find any implementation of this methods in documentation or from a Google search.
Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in react-native source code.
If you want use `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableOpacity` components building Android TV application, you shoulde use this methods `touchableHandleActivePressIn`,  `touchableHandleActivePressOut`, `touchableHandlePress` like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  myMethod = () => {
      console.log('Working');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity touchableHandleActivePressIn onPressIn={this.myMethod}>
           <Text>Placeholder</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

AndroidTV component method handler must be declared as a prop and method to invoke must be declared in respectively:
`onPressIn` for `touchableHandleActivePressIn`,
`onPressOut` for `touchableHandleActivePressOut`,
 and standard `onPress` for `touchableHandlePress`.

Hope this help anyone, it took me 2 days to figure it out, because of lack in official documentation.

Comment: Can you please paste your code which decalres as prop u mentioned in comment. I am new to react native

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple bugs in your code. First, you are creating a `TouchableHightlight` tag. That is a typo -- it should actually be `TouchableHighlight`.  You are also closing that tag with `</TouchableOpacity>`. You need that closing tag to match, like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  myMethod = () => {
      console.log('Working');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight touchableHandleActivePressIn={this.myMethod}>
           <Text>Placeholder</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight >
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

If you'd prefer this element to be a `TouchableOpacity` element (which is different from `TouchableHighlight`) you'd want it to look like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  myMethod = () => {
      console.log('Working');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity touchableHandleActivePressIn={this.myMethod}>
           <Text>Placeholder</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I just wrote it fast to give context of my situation. It's all good without typos in code. The thing is that this method dont work, and Im not sure if I use it correctly.

Comment: Can you update your post with the *actual* code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I am having an issue too on android tv. I can confirm that d-pad navigation is working because I can randomly click on the button and see the different screen; However, I do not see either UI change when I focus in/out and the events as described on the comment above.

1. **onPressIn** for **touchableHandleActivePressIn**
2. **onPressOut** for **touchableHandleActivePressOut**,
3. **standard** onPress for **touchableHandlePress**.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/reactnativetv/